# How to know which configuration to use in application.properties in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

Like the title, I would like to ask how to know what config I want, and remember, and where to look up,... since there are like a billion of them, and there are no auto suggestion in the IDE.

I am following a Plural Sight course and the author just glosses over them without explaining line by line. For example:

```
// application.properties file
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conference_demo
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Like what is `spring.jpa.database-platform` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate` do, and more importantly, if I work on a project myself, ***how do I know if I need them***, and ***MAYBE there are many other config I may need but I don't know of***.

I am not specifically asking what these 2 configs do, I can google it. But more like, how do I navigate in this config mess myself.
It just... a lot!

Thank you all in advance, I really appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Use a better IDE. Intellij has out-of-the-box support for Eclipse you need to use the Spring Toolsuite (either as a product or plugin). Finally check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) which has (most of) them listed.

Comment: @M.Deinum But I don't know when to use what, that's the major problem. How do I know which config I will need?

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation? It has sections for different technologies, if you don't need the technology you don't need the properties. If you need the technology and don't understand the properties you might want to reconsider using that technology or first learn more about said technology.